# CSP blocking route from loading response - FLASK

Tags: python, rest, flask, web-deployment

When I run this flask app in dev mode(app.run) the route('/counties') works well and returns an array of JSONs, however when I use a production server (waitress), Content-Security-Policy(CSP) blocks the route from loading the data.

Message I get : Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:5000/ (“default-src”).

What policy do I need set on my CSP header to avoid this from happening? Or is there anything I need to do? Thank you

```
@app.route('/counties', methods=['GET'])
def get_counties():
    global sql
   
    try:
        counties = sql.get_counties()
        
        return make_response (jsonify({'data':counties}), 200)
    except:
        return make_response(jsonify({'request':{}}), 500, )

@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self';"
    return response
```

Comment: I can see that in your case `'self'` is not cover `http://localhost:5000/`. Do you try to access production server via `http://localhost:5000/` instead of real domain name?

Comment: @granty, yes it does the same thing

Comment: `'self'` could be tricky and it does not allow to mix `http:/localhost:5000/file.css` with `http:/localhost/file.css` or `http:/domain.com/file.css`. Can you show Chrome browser error in Dev tool? Firefox is not verbose enough.